# I want my label.caption value to change due to the value input in text.text

Tags: vb6

I'm learning to program with "VISUAL BASIC 6.0". I want my label1.caption value to change with respect to the value in the textbox1.caption... the code i'm using is below, but its still not working. please help me out. Regards.

```
If Val(Text1) > 0 And Val(Text1) < 39 Then
  Label20.Caption = "0"
Else
  If Val(Text1) > 40 And Val(Text1) < 44 Then
    Label20.Caption = "1"
  Else
    If Val(Text1) > 45 And Val(Text1) < 49 Then
      Label20.Caption = "2"
    Else
      If Val(Text1) > 50 And Val(Text1) < 59 Then
        Label20.Caption = "3"
      Else
        If Val(Text1) > 60 And Val(Text1) < 69 Then
          Label20.Caption = "4"
        Else
          If Val(Text1) > 70 And Val(Text1) < 100 Then
            Label20.Caption = "5"
          End If
```

Comment: If you're using VB6 why have you tagged this VBA and VB.NET?

Comment: _is not working_ don't tell us that, tell us what error do you get. And Visual Basic 6.0 has nothing to do with Visual Studio 2010 and very little in common with VB.NET. Please be more clear

Comment: Shot gunning the tags is not going to help you get an answer. Tag it with the tags that directly relate to your question in this case vb6

Comment: How (from what event), are you calling this Sub?

Comment: Thanks for the hint everyone. I'm new around here, i thought i could just tag as many VB users as possible. i'm sorry if i upset you.

Comment: You use a lot of "if" statements, but i see only 1 "end if" ... make sure you use an "end if" for every "if" ... properly indenting your code will help with that ... i edited your post to show what i mean

Answer (score 0):

0, 39, 40, 44, 45, 49, 50, 59, 60, 69, 70, and 100 won't fire above. Use `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: Hi. thanks a lot for the help, i tried it, but its giving me an error message "Block If without End If"

Comment: What i'm actually trying to do is "a program to computer GP" for students. the numbers above show the general African grading system.

Comment: Remove the `end if` line.

Comment: @D.Ddgg : instead of removing the "end if" he should add 5 more "end if"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using that code in the Text1_Change event? If not, you should :-)

Here is a text project which I think is what you mean:

```
'1 form with
'  1 textbox : name=Text1
'  1 label   : name=Label1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Text1_Change()
  Dim lngVal As Long
  lngVal = Val(Text1.Text)
  Select Case lngVal
    Case 0 To 39
      Label1.Caption = "0"
    Case 40 To 44
      Label1.Caption = "1"
    Case 45 To 49
      Label1.Caption = "2"
    Case 50 To 59
      Label1.Caption = "3"
    Case 60 To 69
      Label1.Caption = "4"
    Case 70 To 100
      Label1.Caption = "5"
    Case Else 'clear label to show something unexpected was entered
      Label1.Caption = ""
  End Select
End Sub
```

I guess the Textbox should only contain numbers? To make sure it can only receive numbers you can add the following:

```
Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case vbKeyBack        'allow the backspace
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9 'allow keys 0 to 9
    Case Else             'dont accept any other input
      KeyAscii = 0
  End Select
End Sub
```

Some other tips:

- don't rely on the default property of a control (.text of a textbox) but write it out to prevent unexpected results
- use select..case instead of a list of if..then statements
- always include a finale 'else' to capture input which doesnt fit into your requirements
- indent your code so you can easily see if you are missing an "end if"